# Noob question about hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a class called User which has 2 properties : login/password. I am trying to authenticate a user in my application using hibernate criteria but my request doesn't work.

[EDIT] The returned value is NULL. I have two users in my database for testing.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
public User authenticate(String login, String password)
    throws NullPointerException {
    Session session = this.getSession();
    User user = (User) session
        .createCriteria(User.class)
        .add(
                        Restrictions.and(
                            Property.forName("login").eq(login),
                            Property.forName("password").eq(password)
                    )).uniqueResult();

    if (user == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("User not found");
    }

    return user;
}
```

Can someone tells me what is wrong with my code?

Happy new Year 2011 !!

Comment: What are you getting back/what is happening when you run the code?

Comment: Well, I don't see anything syntactically wrong in the code you've shown us.  Does it work if you remove the password condition?  (i.e. just search by 'login').

Comment: Yeah, i tried to search only by login, but the returned user is always null. I don't understand what is the problem. My mapping is very simple : 2 properties (login/password with getters and setters).

Comment: Perhaps problem is in something other than you query. Make sure your `login` and `password` actually match values in the database, there are no encoding problems, etc.

Comment: So you're storing the password in cleartext?

Comment: It is a homework. I will not use it in prod.

Comment: You shouldn't throw NullpointerExceptions. Throw a `UnknownUserexception` (you have to create such a Exception). Throwing a NullPointerException is extremly bad codestyle.

Comment: Do you have an `@Id`-Column? If you enlist all Entities, are they found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first retrieve the user from the database. If the user does not exist then show a message on your login page. All of your login names should be in `unique` column so there will be no need to press the `uniqueResult` restriction.

Second, once you got the user pulled up, you just compare the password hash and if it is OK let the user pass through.

The above will simplify your Hibernate logic and hence make your code easier to troubleshoot. 
This is how most sites have it done. At-least as far as I'm concerned.